# Predicting Multivariate time series model (MARSS) with covariates

Tags: r, forecasting, state-space

I am running a multivariate autoregressive state-space model using the MARSS package. I get an error when attempting to predict. This is the code -

```
library(MARSS)

A = "zero"
U = "zero"
B = "identity"
Z = "identity"
Q = "equalvarcov"
R = "equalvarcov"
C = "unconstrained"
y = rbind(rnorm(30))
covariates = rbind(x = rnorm(30))
model.list = list(B=B,U=U,Q=Q,Z=Z,A=A,R=R,C=C,c=covariates)
control.list = list(maxit=500)
MARSS.MODEL = MARSS(y, model=model.list, control=control.list)
newdata <-  rbind(x = rnorm(10))
predict(MARSS.MODEL, newdata=list(c=newdata),n.ahead=10,t.start=31)
```

This is the error -

```
Error: predict_marxss: c are time-varying.In this case, you cannot forecast past the end of the time series(t.start+n.ahead must be < length of original data).
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and I got a different error. Your t.start value is more than the length of the original data. It should be less than 30. I set t.start to 1, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for checking, but from my understanding when setting t.start=1, that would run the model predictions from the start of the original data. As per help page of predict.marssMLE {MARSS}: "A what t to start the prediction relative to the start (t=1) of the data to which the model was fit. The default is to start at t=T+1, where T is the length of the data to which the model was fit. For example, if TT=10, t.start=1 and n.ahead = 5, prediction is for time steps 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 so is not past the end of the data."

Comment: @DarwinBlackbeard Yes, you are reading the help file correctly, but `MARSS::predict()` is still in development, and at present will not work outside the range of the data.